# jQuery Cycle2 per-slide speed option

Tags: jquery-cycle2, cycle2

I can change **timeout** using the timeoutFn. How can I do the same for **speed**? I seached and could not find any way other that having the data-speed attribute on the slide elements. Is there any way to change that programmatically?

```
$('.slideshow').cycle({
                speed: 100,
                timeoutFn: calculateTimeout,
                slides: "li",
                fx: 'scrollLeft,scrollDown,scrollRight'
});

function calculateTimeout(currElement, nextElement, opts, isForward) { 
        var currentElementTransition = $(currElement).attr('data-timeout');
        return parseInt(currentElementTransition, 10) || 0; 
}
```